# Symfony2 using Thread

Tags: mysql, xml, multithreading, symfony

I have large xml files (35 Mb - 80 Mb) in different schemas. I want to record that data into mysql.But loop takes too long and MAMP server crashes but phpmyadmin not. Another page is not running.
How can I solve this problem?

```
 foreach ($xml_object as $items):
    foreach ($items as $item):
        $result = $this->myORMRecordFunction($item);
    endforeach;
 endforeach;
```

Comment: What do you mean with "crash"? Do you get a stacktrace? error?

Comment: MAMP server waiting for loop process and doesn't execute any page.

Comment: Your first step would be to use XMLReader which streams input so the entire xml file does not get loaded in one gulp.

Comment: i understand @Cerad. i am using `simplexml_load_string` function. XMLReader is rather than this function . But other problem? how can i use Thread class or bundle symfony2?